# Pegando so o ultimo cadastro

Tags: php

Estou usando esse code para pegar os dados que estao entre a hora atual e hora cadastrada no bd

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM acessos WHERE hora > :hora GROUP BY username";
$sql = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sql->bindValue(":hora", date('H:i:s', strtotime("-1 minutes")));
$sql->execute();
$contagem = $sql->rowCount();

while($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    $teste = $row['username'].', ';
}
```

Mas o problema que so esta pegando o ultimo cadastro, e não consegui resolver

Comment: O que te dá se tirares `GROUP BY username` da query?

Comment: Por favor, de mais detalhes sobre a tabela e como você quer retornar esses dados. Por exemplo, porque está fazendo esse group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a função **fetchAll** ao invés da **fetch**

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM acessos WHERE hora > :hora GROUP BY username';
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(":hora", date('H:i:s', strtotime('-1 minutes')));
$statement->execute();

$resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Mostra resultados
var_dump($resultado);
```

Referências:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Obrigado Felipe, resolveu meu problema :)

Comment: Opa, bom saber, se puder dar uma lida nesse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers para saber como prosseguir após ter sua pergunta respondida ;)